# Spring cloud contracts plugin change sourceset

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I've started using Spring Cloud Contracts ('2.0.2.RELEASE') in my project and I have the following structure

```
src
|
  -- main
  -- test
  -- integrationTest
  -- contractTest
```

When I put my contracts and my base test class in test it was running fine. I want to move the contract tests that I have written into a separate sourceset, the contractTest sources. However, this will not work as the plugin `generateContractTests` task will still look in the test sourceset when trying to run.

I have made the following changes to my Gradle file

```
task contractTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs contract tests.'
    group = 'verification'

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.contractTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.contractTest.runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter integrationTest
}
configurations {
    contractTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
    contractTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
}
sourceSets {
    contractTest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    }
}
contracts {
//    testFramework = 'JUNIT5'
    packageWithBaseClasses = 'com.test.testapi.contracts'
    contractsDslDir = new File("${project.rootDir}/src/contractTest/resources/contracts/")
}
contractTestImplementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.6'
contractTestImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier'
contractTestImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api'
contractTestImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine'
```

I think I need to set the contract plugin property `contractDependency`, however, I am not sure and can't find an example to get the plugin to work with this different sourceset

TLDR; I want to be able to run my contract tests in a different folder

UPDATE - I am not sure but I think that it is not possible as in the Gradle plugin in the "[GenerateServerTestsTask.groovy](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/master/spring-cloud-contract-tools/spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin/src/main/groovy/org/springframework/cloud/contract/verifier/plugin/GenerateServerTestsTask.groovy)" file has the following which would appear to signify that the sourceSet is hardcoded to test throughout the code

```
project.sourceSets.test.groovy {
    project.logger.
            info("Registering ${getConfigProperties().generatedTestSourcesDir} as test source directory")
    srcDir getConfigProperties().getGeneratedTestSourcesDir()
}
```

Comment: I don't think you're right. What that code says is that it adds to classpath the generated tests. You want to change the source where the contacts are stored right? You have to setup the gradle plugin and provide the new location

Comment: Thanks for getting back.
I want to setup the plugin to work with my new "contractTest" test task. This is a separate test task from the normal test task. I personally have the tests just for my unit tests and want my contracts and base classes in the new  contractTest sourceset.
I believ that the contract plugin depends on the check task. The test task depends on check so I it is a case where the gradle plugin would only run with the test classpath.

If there is a better way to discuss this or to explain a bit more please let me know. if it is an enhancement I would be keen to PR it back

Comment: Please create a sample @ Github and describe in the README.adoc what exactly you're trying to achieve and how to replicate the issue

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak I have now done this. https://github.com/Budlee/ContractTestDemo
Thanks

Comment: I'm not a Gradle expert. It seems that first Groovy is missing from the classpath (if you uncomment `testImplementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.6'`, some other things are missing). I don't see this as a problem with sc-contract, but a problem with Gradle setup.

Comment: No it works fine with the previous commit when it is included and is expected as the contracts are in the test sourceset and the contract verification takes place in the test task. With the latest commit the one that fails it is not working as from what I can tell it is not possible  to run contract tests in anything else but the test task. You can see in the build.gradle it is expeciltly commented out as I do not want the dependency on test as I want to run the contract test with the contrarTest task. If you pull the project and I comment that line you will still see that it fails

Comment: Isn't it here: project.tasks.findByName("compileTestJava").dependsOn(task) in the file SpringCloudContractVerifierGradlePlugin. The explicit depend is written here and I effectively am looking to move this out to my own task from my new sources: compileContractTestJava. `gradle contractTest --dry-run
:compileJava SKIPPED
:compileGroovy SKIPPED
:processResources SKIPPED
:classes SKIPPED
:compileContractTestJava SKIPPED
:compileContractTestGroovy SKIPPED
:processContractTestResources SKIPPED
:contractTestClasses SKIPPED
:contractTest SKIPPED`

Comment: and the difference here: `gradle test --dry-run
:compileJava SKIPPED
:compileGroovy SKIPPED
:processResources SKIPPED
:classes SKIPPED
:copyContracts SKIPPED
:generateContractTests SKIPPED
:compileTestJava SKIPPED
:compileTestGroovy SKIPPED
:processTestResources SKIPPED
:testClasses SKIPPED
:test SKIPPED
`
Because the depend is explicit it can't be changed which means it could not work with other source sets and in other tasks. I think this could be an enhancement. I'll open an issue and put in a PR if you think this is fair

Comment: Why not. Let's move it to a pr

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak, do you have the PR link? Thanks.

Comment: Not that I recall really

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, I was able to get it working by creating a custom task to deregister the generated sources from the test sourceset so that they wouldn't be compiled by compileTestJava and could be run via my own contractTests task.

```
sourceSets {
     contractTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            srcDir file('src/contractTest/java')
            srcDirs += file("${buildDir}/generated-contract-sources/")
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/contractTest/resources')
    }
}

task deregisterContractTestSources() {
    doLast {
        project.sourceSets.test.java {
            project.logger.info('Removing any *Spec classes from the test sources')
            exclude '**/*Spec*'
        }
    }
}
compileTestJava.dependsOn deregisterContractTestSources

task contractTests(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs contract tests'
    group = 'verification'

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.contractTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.contractTest.runtimeClasspath
}

contracts {
    baseClassForTests = 'com'
    generatedTestSourcesDir = file("${buildDir}/generated-contract-sources")
    generatedTestResourcesDir = file("${buildDir}/generated-contract-resources/")
    testFramework = "JUNIT5"
    contractsDslDir = new File("${projectDir}/src/contractTest/resources/contracts/")
    nameSuffixForTests = 'Spec'
    basePackageForTests = 'com'
}
```